# Why is my ubuntu 16.04.1 black screen after restart?

Tags: system-installation

When I downloaded Ubuntu 16..04.1 and installed it, it works fine, but when I restarted it, it's black screen... How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Well depending on which Distro of Ubuntu this is there is two ways you can fix this.

## Ubuntu Recovery Mode:

To access Ubuntu Recovery Mode:

- Turn on your computer. (Obviously)
- Wait for BIOS to load, then right after it does, strike "Shift" and hold it until you see the GRUB Menu. (If you see an Ubuntu Logo or Text, you're too late.)
- Select "Advanced Options"
- Select the option that has "Recovery Mode" at the end of it and hit ENTER
- First try the "dpkg" option to see if its a missing dependency (First choose "Network" to enable Networking...)
- If not, try "failsafeX" to see if its just a Driver Issue.

## Terminal Login

Now unless there's a kernel panic at the end of bootup, you should still be able to access a Terminal interface, what you want to do is once you see a black screen, press **"F1"** or **Fn+F1"** and you should see a terminal interface that should ask you to Login. If you get to this stage then play around a bit and see if maybe a missing dependency or driver is causing the error with XOrg.

Best of Luck!

Comment: What is BIOS anyway?

Comment: I am installing a new Ubuntu 16.04 now...When 30 seconds is done, its gonna be black screen and when 30 seconds is done again, it will be back...why?